# Black screen in vmware during installation

Tags: vmware

During installation, it shows a black screen with a blinking underscore. What can be the cause of this? And how I can resolve this?

Comment: Are you trying to install any OS without boot file? If YES then your VM has not booted up because the boot might get corrupted try reinstalling the OS with correct iso files.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be caused by any of the following reasons -

1. Incorrect version of VMware SVGA driver in VM.
2. Low availability of video RAM.
3. Due to the weak processor.

Some resolution steps that you can try -

1. Boot the virtual machine into safe mode.
2. In the device manager, change the driver for the VGA card to the standard MS VGA Driver.
3. Make sure you install the latest correct version of VMware tools.